# Variable definition changes in Bash

Tags: bash

In Bash 3.00.16, the following prints `defined`, and in Bash 4.2.24 it prints `undefined`:

```
my_test() {
    local foo
    if [ -n "${foo+defined}" ]
    then
        echo defined
    else
        echo undefined
    fi
}
my_test
```

I couldn't find anything obviously relevant on the [Bash changes](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/bashchanges) page.

- When was this changed?
- Was this considered a bug fix, or a side effect of some other change? In other words, can the current behavior be considered stable?

Comment: I don't quite know the answer to your questions (when and why the change), but what I do know is that the vast majority of Linux distributions (what are you using, by the way?) now use bash 4.x .

Comment: @l0b0 By the way, there is notice at page on your link, that *article is an incomplete overview*. Moreover, I've found nothing about `${foo+defined}` construction in man. There is only `${foo:+defined}` which works the same way in both versions.

Comment: @rush: The man page has a very brief sentence about the colon with these operators: "Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset". This behavior exists in 3.2; I don't know if it is earlier as well. This is defined in POSIX as well: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behaviour changes from Bash 4.0 onwards and it looks like a variable scope bug fix. The behaviour of your code changes based on the existence of global variables of the same name.

In versions prior to 4.0

- If you have a global `variable` defined with the same name as the local, `${variable+override}` will work as documented.
- If you don't have a global variable, `${variable+override}` will use the override value.

That's kind of the opposite of what you would normally expect of a global scope issue. Maybe having the global causes `local` to set up the variable differently in earlier versions of Bash or maybe `+` looks up variables in a different manner.

As @rush mentioned, you get consistent behaviour in all versions if you use `${foo:+defined}`. <strike>I couldn't find much documentation on using just the plus symbol either, except for references to using `${1+"$@"}` which there is a test for in the source.</strike>  @choroba and @chepner added that `man bash` explains that *Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset*.

Using the following modified function (having the function named the same as the variable did not impact anything, but it was the first thing I thought might be triggering the bug):

```
foo() {
    echo "global bar [${bar+defined}]"
    local bar
    echo "local bar  [${bar+defined}]"
}
```

4.0.0(1)-release

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.0.0(1)-release
$ unset bar
$ foo
global bar []
local bar  []
$ bar=test
$ foo
global bar [defined]
local bar  []
```

3.2.0(1)-release

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.0(1)-release
$ unset bar
$ foo
global bar []
local bar  [defined]
$ bar=test
$ foo
global bar [defined]
local bar  []
```

3.00.16(1)-release

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.00.16(1)-release
$ unset bar
$ foo
global bar []
local bar  [defined]
$ bar=test
$ foo
global bar [defined]
local bar  []
```

2.05b.0(1)-release

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
2.05b.0(1)-release
$ unset bar
$ foo
global bar []
local bar  [defined]
$ bar=test
$ foo
global bar [defined]
local bar  []
```

Comment: Excellent answer! I was hoping to avoid `:+` because of the semantic difference, but it looks like it's unfeasible for now.

Comment: `man bash` mentions omitting the colon: 
*When not performing substring expansion, using the forms documented below, bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null. Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.*